# "after he was cleared of killing at center of hit documentary"

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Making a Murderer's Brendan Dassey is 'scared' of outside world says his mother as clock ticks down to freedom after he was cleared of killing **at center of hit documentary**.*

Source: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3770899/Making-Murderer-s-Brendan-Dassey-s-mother-speaks-time-son-s-conviction-overturned-saying-s-excited-released-scared-facing-outside-world.html

I am not able to fully understand the phrase "at center of hit documentary". It seems as if this phrase was related to the part "killing" but it does not make much sense.

Comment: It's headlinese, for one thing.  Without having seen the documentary to know the context, that headline could be understood in two ways: the killing is depicted at the center of the documentary, or that is where his being cleared occurs.

Comment: @TRomano: The other "two ways" to understand it are: 1) - The killing (or being cleared of it) featured *in the middle of* the documentary (in the fifth of ten episodes, say), or 2) - It was *central* to the documentary (most or all of the documentary was primarily focused on this issue). Native speakers would unhesitatingly assume the second of those, but from a learner's point of view this might not be so obvious.

Comment: ***...hit** documentary* is perhaps an unfortunate choice there, since it's not a documentary *about a "hit"* (a gangland "contracted killing / assassination").

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Agreed. The documentary is all about the killing. The killing is its main subject. That's how I'd understand "at center of" when push comes to shove.

Comment: @bart-leby: Even disregarding mine and TRomoano's comments, do you still have a problem if I tell you to parse it as *...after he was cleared of **the** killing **which was** at **the** center of **the** hit documentary?* I'm not sure exactly what you're struggling with, or how to resolve the issue.

Comment: You both helped me. Thank you. Even if I know the TV show I was not sure how to understand the passage in question. The condensation of the information in the headline seems to me to be a little bit puzzled.

Comment: It could easily be intended to mean both. Headline writers often intentionally embed a pun into a headline; it's almost an art. For example, a recent Wall Street Journal article about loafers (a kind of shoe) had this headline: _The Loafer Steps Up_. Surely the inclusion of that phrasal verb – one that conjures up images of feet – was no accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Daily Mail is using a *play on words* in their headline.

> a hit

can have two meanings:

1) *something* that is very popular
2) a gangland-style murder

Parts of the Brendan Dassey murder story was featured on *Making A Murderer* for the killing of Teresa Haibach.  The murder might be termed a "hit", although Dassey was not part of any organised crime syndicate.

*Making a Murder* was first released in 2015 and achieved a high international following, and its efforts lead to petition of over 100,000 signatures to clear Steven Avery.  The high viewing ratings would qualify *Making A Murderer* a "hit" program as noted by the Daily Mail further along in the same article.

Dassey's conviction has recently been overturned, and his Mother has made an appeal to the viewers of Netflix, the distributors of *Making A Murderer*.

Comment: I won't actually *downvote*, but I really don't think it's likely the Daily Mail would have *deliberately* included that "pun". It's a very weak allusion (especially given *hit = assassination* is primarily AmE, and that's not what he was accused of anyway), so I'd say it's just a quirky point that nobody would have noticed until we put it under the microscope here.

Comment: From the Daily Mail: [SPOILER ALERT: Roxy Mitchell disappears as Derek Branning pays a hitman to take her out on EastEnders](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-2101562/Eastenders-hitman-horror-Roxy-Mitchell-disappears-Derek-Branning-pays-hit-man-out.html#ixzz4JL6hOLFz)